# Passing value to case statement in bash

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I was writing a code for the assembler in shell scripting (below is a portion of it). It has to convert assembly mnemonics into machine code which are correspondingly mapped in the cases inside the "code" subroutine. But if $currComm is set to "D = A" the $comp_mne which will now be set to A (inside comp subroutine) is not getting into the corresponding case for it in "code" subroutine. Instead it goes into the default case printing "invalid comp".

```
comp()
{
    if [ `echo $currComm | awk '{print $2}'` = "=" ] ; then
        comp_mne="`echo $currComm | awk '{print $3}'`"
    elif [ `echo $currComm | awk '{print $2}'` = "\;" ] ; then
        comp_mne="`echo $currComm | awk '{print $1}'`"
    fi
    echo "comp is $comp_mne"
    code
}
code()
{
     echo "checking for comp $comp_mne"
     case "$comp_mne" in  
        "0") 
            echo -n "0101010-" >> ${file}.hack 
            ;;
        "1") 
            echo -n "0111111-" >> ${file}.hack 
            ;;
        "-1") 
            echo -n "0111010-" >> ${file}.hack 
            ;;
        "D") 
            echo -n "0001100-" >> ${file}.hack 
            ;;
        "A") 
            echo -n "0110000-" >> ${file}.hack
            echo "found" 
            ;;
        "!D") 
            echo -n "0001101-" >> ${file}.hack 
            ;;
        "!A") 
            echo -n "0110001-" >> ${file}.hack 
            ;;
        "-D") 
            echo -n "0001111-" >> ${file}.hack 
            ;;
        "-A") 
            echo -n "0110011-" >> ${file}.hack 
            ;;
        "D+1") 
            echo -n "0011111-" >> ${file}.hack 
            ;;
        *) 
            echo "Invalid comp"
            ;;
        esac
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\`echo $currComm | awk '{print $2}'\`
```

evaluates to a literal string containing those commands; it does *not* execute those commands. When you put a backslash in front of a character that character loses its special meaning and becomes a literal.

What you want is this:

```
"$(awk '{print $2}' <<< "$currComm")"
```

- Gets rid of an unnecessary and risky `echo`. Another safe method is replacing `echo` with `printf '%s'`
- [Quotes](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) values.
- Uses modern [command substitutions](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/CommandSubstitution).

Comment: Actually the backslashes in \`echo $currComm | awk '{print $2}'\` showed up by mistake. I did not put these in my code

Comment: I tried above solution but it didn't work, giving the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Your case statement can have:

```
"D"*)   # Matches on any $comp_mne starting with D
        ;;
```

The problem will be that the "D+1" case lower down will no longer be triggered, since "D"* matches $comp_mne=D+1.  So you have to be careful on what you match on.